Error Issue with functions "estimate_pls" from SEMinR library
I'm trying to build a path model using the SEMinR library. This is the code I'm trying to run :
mediated_sm <- relationships(
  paths(from = "clicks_2095320", to = "total_conversions")
  )

mediated_model <- estimate_pls(data = Dataset2,
                               structural_model = mediated_sm)

My dataframe has multiple columns but I made sure that the names are correct so it should be could, but instead I have this error :
"""
Generating the seminr model
Error in [.data.frame(data, , i) : undefined columns selected
"""

Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible example to help us identify where the problem is. See community guide here for more details.
